# How to get a tuple from two lists of elements

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, tuples

I have two lists of `UIViews`, some of that `UIViews` have an `accessibilityIdentifier` most of them are `nil`.
I'm searching for a way to generate a tuple(or something) with the two `UIViews` from the lists that have the same `accessibilityIdentifier`.

The lists are not sorted or something.

Is there a way to not iterate multiple times through the second list to find every pair?

```
for view in firstViewList {
   if view.accessibilityIdentifier != nil {
       for secondView in secondViewList {
           if secondView.accessibilityIdentifier != nil && secondView.accessibilityIdentifier == view.accessibilityIdentifier {
               viewPairs.append((firstView: view, secondView: secondView))
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I think this is not very efficient.

Comment: What you are doing is the most efficient in terms of time complexity. I don't think you can make it faster than O(n^2).

Comment: @Sweeper Nope, you can do it it O(N). Constructing two dictionaries, and finding the intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dict that indexes both view lists by their ID, filter out the ones where the ID is nil, and then use the keys common to both dicts to create a new dict that indexes pairs of same-id views.

Here's a rough example (which I haven't compiled myself).

```
func makeDictByAccessibilityID(_ views: [UIView]) -> [AccessibilityID: UIView] {
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
        firstViewList
            .lazy
            .map { (id: $0.accessibilityIdentifier, view: $0) }
            .filter { $0.id != nil }
    )
}

viewsByAccessibilityID1 = makeDictByAccessibilityID(firstViewList)
viewsByAccessibilityID2 = makeDictByAccessibilityID(secondViewList)
commonIDs = Set(viewsByAccessibilityID1.keys).intersecting(
                Set(viewsByAccessibilityID2.keys)
            )

let viewPairsByAccessibilityID = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
    commonIDs.lazy.map { id in
        // Justified force unwrap, because we specifically defined the keys as being available in both dicts.
        (key: id, viewPair: (viewsByAccessibilityID1[id]!, viewsByAccessibilityID2[id]!))
    }
}
```

This runs in O(n) time, which is the best you can get for this problem.

Comment: Nice! Just a question, why lazy?

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla Why make an array of tuples, only to have the dict initializer read it, and immediately discard it? Laziness allows the program to skip making the intermediate array.

Comment: Thanks!! Very nice answer. Learned something new with it

Comment: Won't the `Dictionary` initializer consume the whole lazy collection anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first filtered your two arrays from the nil value then you can do like this

```
let tempfirstViewList = firstViewList.filter { (view) -> Bool in
view.accessibilityIdentifier != nil
}
var tempsecondViewList = secondViewList.filter { (view) -> Bool in
view.accessibilityIdentifier != nil
}
tempfirstViewList.forEach { (view) in
let filterdSecondViewList = tempsecondViewList.filter { (secondView) -> Bool in
     secondView.accessibilityIdentifier == view.accessibilityIdentifier
}
if let sView = filterdSecondViewList.first {
    viewPairs.append((firstView: view, secondView: sView))
//after add it to your tuple remove it from the temp array to not loop throw it again
    if let index = tempsecondViewList.firstIndex(of: sView) {
        tempsecondViewList.remove(at: index)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought about that. So I just iter through Views with identifiers. To remove it from the lists is also a good idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates an array of tuples with views from the first and second list respectively

```
var viewArray: [(UIView, UIView)]
firstViewList.forEach( { view in
    if let identifier = view.accessibilityIdentifier {
       let arr = secondViewList.filter( {$0.accessibilityIdentifier == identifier} )
        arr.forEach( { viewArray.append((view, $0))})
    }
})
```